# Java Interview question: Make combinations from 2 arrays, with no duplicates and output must be in random

Tags: java, combinations

The question is:
Assume there is a Rich Businessman, He has 20 Cars, 50 Watches. He is very particular in maintaining his uniqueness, so he wants a program to select distinct combination of Car and Watch for each day by the conditions given below.
His requirement is to get a random, non-repeated car and watch for complete cycle of their availability.
Ex:

1. As he as 20 cars, same car should not come for 20 days once used. Also, they should come in random.
2. If one day Car 1 and Watch 2 was selected, it should not come for next one month.

I was approaching the problem to make a list of Pair combinations and populate the list in random, however in doing so I was getting duplicates. So not sure if I should consider using another DS or change my approach altogether to better design and implement this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class PairSelector {

    private List<Pair> pairs;


    public PairSelector() {
        pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();

        IntStream.range(0,20).forEach(i -> {
            IntStream.range(0,50).forEach(j -> {
                if (i != j) {
                    pairs.add(new Pair(i, j));
                }
            });

        });
    }

    public Pair getRandomPair() {
        return pairs.get((int) (pairs.size() * Math.random()));
    }
}

class Pair {
    private int car;
    private int watch;

    public Pair(int car, int watch) {
        this.car = car;
        this.watch = watch;
    }
    public int getCar() {
        return car;
    }
    public int getWatch() {
        return watch;
    }
}


public class RichBusinessman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            PairSelector ps = new PairSelector();
            Pair randomPair = ps.getRandomPair();

            int car = randomPair.getCar();
            int watch = randomPair.getWatch();

            System.out.println("car: " + car + ", watch: " + watch);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal i dont think that is the issue. I think he is having issue with the logic to generate random pairs, and  to check if the pair fulfills the condition if not, generate new pairs until it fulfills conditions. For one thing, he will surely need another ordered collection to store the already chosen pairs

Comment: @YHStan yes that is very accurate. I did try implements Sets tho after Rishabh's suggestion but even tho the pairs are unique, the car number and watch number repeats. So yes need an update in the logic

Comment: This part of the spec is confusing `If one day Car 1 and Watch 2 was selected, it should not come for next one month`. Do you mean that combination shouldn't occur until next 50-day cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. I made two new helper methods for the pairselector class. This does not account for other unmentioned conditions such as what Fede Garcia mentioned.

```
    public Pair getRandomPair() {
        while (true){
            int index = (int) (pairs.size() * Math.random());
            int car = pairs.get(index).getCar();
            int watch = pairs.get(index).getWatch();
            int caridx = lastidxofCar(car);
            int watchidx = lastidxofWatch(watch);

            if (caridx != -1){
                if (used.size() - caridx < 20){
                    //checking first condition
                    continue;
                }

                //passes first condition
                if (caridx == watchidx ){
                    if (used.size() - caridx <30){
                        //checking second condition
                        continue;
                    }
                    //not a must to remove
//                    else{
//                        used.remove(caridx);
//                    }
                }
                //passes second condition
            }

            if (watchidx != -1){
                //check that watch is also not repeated for the 50 varieties
                if (used.size() - watchidx < 50){
                    //checking first condition
                    continue;
                }
            }

            used.add(pairs.get(index));
            //System.out.println(index+", "+caridx+","+watchidx+", "+(used.size()-caridx));
            return pairs.get(index);
        }
    }
    
        public int lastidxofCar(int car){
            for (int i=used.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
                if (used.get(i).getCar() == car){
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    
        public int lastidxofWatch(int watch){
            for (int i= used.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
                if (used.get(i).getWatch() == watch){
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

and I modified your main method slightly. This might not fully work if there are any other conditions i am unaware of.

```
PairSelector ps = new PairSelector();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        //PairSelector ps = new PairSelector();
        //this causes the used list to be "reset" everytime an iteration occurs
        Pair randomPair = ps.getRandomPair();

        int car = randomPair.getCar();
        int watch = randomPair.getWatch();

        System.out.println("car: " + car + ", watch: " + watch);
    }
```

Output:

```
car: 18, watch: 12
car: 8, watch: 0
car: 9, watch: 20
car: 13, watch: 28
car: 6, watch: 10
car: 12, watch: 28
car: 1, watch: 18
car: 19, watch: 45
car: 7, watch: 16
car: 14, watch: 10
car: 11, watch: 0
car: 16, watch: 21
car: 17, watch: 27
car: 10, watch: 9
car: 3, watch: 41
car: 2, watch: 22
car: 0, watch: 20
car: 15, watch: 1
car: 5, watch: 21
car: 4, watch: 22
```

its not fully efficient and there is the scenario of hardcoded days in a month, but its a start.

Answer (score 1):

1. Logic restrictions:

   If 20 cars should not repeat in at least 20 days, the sequence of those 20 cars is *fixed*. Otherwise there is at least one car which will repeat in less than 20 days in two consecutive 20 day sequences.

   So you would only need to shuffle the cars array. There exists a randomizing `Collections.shuffle(List<>)`. So create a list of cars.

   **Comment** this exploitation of the logic restriction.
   This helps to enlighten the interviewer should heshe not realize the logic. And helps excusing any failure on your side to understand the requirements.
2. Pay attention to niceties.

   The private fields can be **final**, which would be nice should you have time to implement `equals/hashcode`.

   ```
    class Pair {
        private final int car;
        private final int watch;
   ```

   By the way you might mention the new `Record` class. It would have saved valuable time in an interview.

   ```
    record Pair(int car, int watch) { }
   ```
3. Logic on watches

   When a car does not repeat itself for 20 days, a month will have at most 2 same cars. So the watch must be different from the previous car's watch.

   So you need a car-to-last-watch map. An array of 20 ints would do if the cars are numbered from 0 to 20-1. Pseudo-code:

   ```
    int[] carWatches = new int[20];
    //Arrays.fill(carWatches, -1); // No watch.

    Random random = new Random();
    int watch = random.nextInt(50 - 1); // Leave a gap for the last watch.
    if (watch >= carWatches[car]) {
        ++watch;
    }
    ... new Pair(car, watch);

    // This means the same watch may be repeated the next day.
   ```

Small solutions like `random.nextIt(50 - 1)` and then `>=` help transmit your expertise.

Comment: Hi Joop, I dont understand the use of `if (watch >= carWatches[car]) {
     ++watch;
 }` I understand the case that if it was equals, you would need to get a new number (random, increment etc.) Can you please explain how the if statement helps your solution?

Comment: You want a random number but not the last one. The code picks one of 49 different numbers. The last number (==) is avoided by ++, but also all after that (>) get a ++, so that indeed 49 **different** numbers are elected. One could also have done `if (watch == ...) { watch = 49; }`.

Comment: oh, i get it now, you are one-shifting the cases so it is ie 0->(x-1) , and x+1 ->50